# CRM 2011 HTML web resource does not work in IE11

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

CRM 2011 html web resource is failing in IE11 with the error "Unable to get property 'CrmUrlEncode' of undefined or null reference". The same web resource works perfectly in IE 10 and less.

The above error is triggering from the method context().getClientUrl() of XrmServiceToolkit (the codeplex library version 2.1). The actual method I am using is XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Retrieve to get a CRM record.

Initially I thought it's compatibility issue as we were on Rollup 15 and one of Microsoft article specified that CRM IE 11 compatibility is released with Rollup 17. Now We have upgraded our environment to Rollup 18 but still the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by the built-in script component `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx`, which is not compatible with Internet Explorer 11. In many cases we need it in our custom HTML web resources to get a proper integration with CRM, so we cannot do without it.

Luckily the solution is easy: add the following metatag to your HTML web resource header:

```
<meta content="IE=10,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

This instructs IE to behave as if it were version 10.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Your solution or suggestion is working fine. I am marking it as answered. But if possible can you please clarify my doubt. What is this meta tag does? is it the same as browser compatibility settings? I am asking because, our Organization is retiring all the previous versions of IE and making IE 11 as standard organization browser to increase the security. Becasue of this reasons they don't want to use browser compatibility settings/mode aswell. Does the usage of this meta tag a security breach again? Please clarify and thanks once again.

Comment: It controls the rendering behaviour of IE. I am not an expert on this topic, but you can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Found a rant on this meta tag by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/meta-madness/). Looks you can have an interesting discussion in your organization. Meanwhile, in Dynamics CRM 2011 you do not have many options. Maybe upgrade to Dynamics CRM 2015?